# useEffect infinite loop occurs only while testing, not otherwise - despite using useReducer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect, use-reducer

I'm trying to test a useFetch custom hook. This is the hook:

```
import React from 'react';

function fetchReducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === `fetch`) {
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: true,
    };
  } else if (action.type === `success`) {
    return {
      data: action.data,
      error: null,
      loading: false,
    };
  } else if (action.type === `error`) {
    return {
      ...state,
      error: action.error,
      loading: false,
    };
  } else {
    throw new Error(
      `Hello! This function doesn't support the action you're trying to do.`
    );
  }
}

export default function useFetch(url, options) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(fetchReducer, {
    data: null,
    error: null,
    loading: true,
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'fetch' });

    fetch(url, options)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => dispatch({ type: 'success', data }))
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'error', error });
      });
  }, [url, options]);

  return {
    loading: state.loading,
    data: state.data,
    error: state.error,
  };
}
```

This is the test

```
import useFetch from "./useFetch";
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import { server, rest } from "../mocks/server";

function getAPIbegin() {
  return renderHook(() =>
    useFetch(
      "http://fe-interview-api-dev.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/begin",
      { method: "GET" },
      1
    )
  );
}

test("fetch should return the right data", async () => {
  const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = getAPIbegin();

  expect(result.current.loading).toBe(true);
  await waitForNextUpdate();
  expect(result.current.loading).toBe(false);
  const response = result.current.data.question;
  expect(response.answers[2]).toBe("i think so");
});

// Overwrite mock with failure case

test("shows server error if the request fails", async () => {
  server.use(
    rest.get(
      "http://fe-interview-api-dev.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/begin",
      async (req, res, ctx) => {
        return res(ctx.status(500));
      }
    )
  );

  const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = getAPIbegin();

  expect(result.current.loading).toBe(true);
  expect(result.current.error).toBe(null);
  expect(result.current.data).toBe(null);
  await waitForNextUpdate();
  console.log(result.current);
  expect(result.current.loading).toBe(false);
  expect(result.current.error).not.toBe(null);
  expect(result.current.data).toBe(null);
});
```

- I keep getting an error only when running the test:
  "Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render."
- The error is coming from TestHook: node_modules/@testing-library/react-hooks/lib/index.js:21:23)
  at Suspense

I can't figure out how to fix this. URL and options have to be in the dependency array, and running the useEffect doesn't change them, so I don't get why it's causing this loop. When I took them out of the array, the test worked, but I need the effect to run again when those things change.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing this is because you're passing in an object as the "options" argument, `{ method: "GET" }`. Every time the hook gets called, it will pass in this new inline object, and React will do a reference comparison and say the options are different, even though these two objects have the same values inside them. Best bet is probably to memoize the options you pass into the hook, or in some way stop a new object getting created every time the hook is called (not sure how that'd work in a test situation).

Comment: @Jayce444 so is the problem that I'm passing an object to the dependency array? Does that mean that if it wasn't an object (eg. I pass each param individually) it wouldn't have this problem?

Comment: Yes I would think so, or if you somehow find a way to properly memoize the object you're passing in. You could test his by having at the top of your test file (under imports) `const OPTIONS = { method: "GET" };` and then passing that as the argument, `useFetch("http://fe-interview-api-dev.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/begin", OPTIONS)`. That object is now a global variable and its reference shouldn't change, so that might fix infinite loop. Hard to say if this is a test only issue, but I'm guessing the issue you currently get in the test would manifest in regular usage too

Comment: @Jayce444 yup it turns out it was a test issue - RenderHook returns an object, so having options outside, as an object itself, was causing RenderHook to get stuck in a rerendering loop. Adding options as a const inside the test, and then passing that in to the useFetch params fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```js
function getAPIbegin(url, options) {
  return renderHook(() =>
    useFetch(url, options)
  );
}

test("fetch should return the right data", async () => {
  const url = "http://fe-interview-api-dev.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/begin";
  const options = { method: "GET" };
  const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = getAPIbegin(url, options);

  expect(result.current.loading).toBe(true);
  await waitForNextUpdate();
  expect(result.current.loading).toBe(false);
  const response = result.current.data.question;
  expect(response.answers[2]).toBe("i think so");
});
```

I haven't used react-hooks-testing-library, but my guess is that whenever React is rendered, the callback send to `RenderHook` will be called repeatedly, causing different options to be passed in each time.

Comment: Thank you @vipcxj - this worked, and your explanation/guess (guessplanation?) about RenderHook was spot on.